# generating gif in javascript with gif.js?

Tags: javascript

I am using https://jnordberg.github.io/gif.js/
I am dynamically creating elements (img) , after generating them, I want to create a gif. I am using the following code but I get the following error:

```
<canvas id="result" width="600" height="600" style='display:none'></canvas><br>

  var res_c = document.getElementById("result");
  var res_ctx = res_c.getContext('2d');
  for (var x = frames.length-1; x >= 0; x--) {
       res_ctx.putImageData(frames[x],0,0);
       var image = document.createElement("img");
       image.src = res_c.toDataURL("image/png");
       $(".frames").append(image);
       gif.addFrame(image);
  }
  gif.render();
  gif.on('finished', function(blob) {
    window.open(URL.createObjectURL(blob));
  });
```

I am getting this error:

```
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'getImageData' on   'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The source height is 0.
at GIF.getContextData
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: It seems that maybe it's not fetching the image your want to render, that's why the source height is zero, there's no image. Also, I don't see where you're defining `res_c`

Comment: @Difster I updated the code.

Comment: Why are you creating a new image element? You shouldn't need that at all. You just need to read in the image source.

I think if you change `var image = document.createElement("img");`  to
`var image = new Image();` and then you might be ok.

Comment: @Difster thanks, but i get same error

Comment: I would try to call `gif.addFrame()` in the `image.onload` event. Setting up the event handler before setting `image.src`.